# Unable to setup Istio with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, containers, minikube, kubernetes-helm, istio

I followed Istio's official documentation to setup Istio for sample bookinfo app with minikube. but I'm getting **Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout**  error. these are the steps that I have followed(I have kubectl & minikube installed).

```
minikube start
curl -L https://git.io/getLatestIstio | sh -
cd istio-1.0.3
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
```

This is the terminal output I'm getting

```
$ kubectl get pods -n istio-system
NAME                                      READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-9cfc9d4c9-xg7bh                   1/1       Running             0          4m
istio-citadel-6d7f9c545b-lwq8s            1/1       Running             0          3m
istio-cleanup-secrets-69hdj               0/1       Completed           0          4m
istio-egressgateway-75dbb8f95d-k6xj2      1/1       Running             0          4m
istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97             0/1       ContainerCreating   0          4m
istio-grafana-post-install-xz9rk          0/1       Completed           0          4m
istio-ingressgateway-6bd4957bc-vhbct      1/1       Running             0          4m
istio-pilot-7f8c49bbd8-x6bmm              0/2       Pending             0          4m
istio-policy-6c65d8cff4-hx2c7             2/2       Running             0          4m
istio-security-post-install-gjfj2         0/1       Completed           0          4m
istio-sidecar-injector-74855c54b9-nnqgx   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          3m
istio-telemetry-65cdd46d6c-rqzfw          2/2       Running             0          4m
istio-tracing-ff94688bb-hgz4h             1/1       Running             0          3m
prometheus-f556886b8-chdxw                1/1       Running             0          4m
servicegraph-778f94d6f8-9xgw5             1/1       Running             0          3m

$kubectl describe pod istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97
Error from server (NotFound): pods "istio-galley-5bf4d6b8f7-8s2z9" not found
```

pod describe output

```
 $ kubectl -n istio-system describe pod  istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97
Name:           istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97
Namespace:      istio-system
Node:           minikube/172.17.0.4
Start Time:     Sat, 03 Nov 2018 04:29:57 +0000
Labels:         istio=galley
                pod-template-hash=1690826493
Annotations:    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod=
                sidecar.istio.io/inject=false
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/istio-galley-5bf4d6b8f7
Containers:
  validator:
    Container ID:
    Image:         gcr.io/istio-release/galley:1.0.0    Image ID:
    Ports:         443/TCP, 9093/TCP    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:      /usr/local/bin/galley
      validator      --deployment-namespace=istio-system
      --caCertFile=/etc/istio/certs/root-cert.pem
      --tlsCertFile=/etc/istio/certs/cert-chain.pem
      --tlsKeyFile=/etc/istio/certs/key.pem
      --healthCheckInterval=2s
      --healthCheckFile=/health
      --webhook-config-file
      /etc/istio/config/validatingwebhookconfiguration.yaml
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        10m
    Liveness:     exec [/usr/local/bin/galley probe --probe-path=/health --interval=4s] delay=4s timeout=1s period=4s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    exec [/usr/local/bin/galley probe --probe-path=/health --interval=4s] delay=4s timeout=1s period=4s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio/certs from certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/config from config (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from istio-galley-service-account-token-9pcmv(ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio.istio-galley-service-account
    Optional:    false
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio-galley-configuration
    Optional:  false
  istio-galley-service-account-token-9pcmv:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-galley-service-account-token-9pcmv
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned istio-galley-5bf4d6b8f7-8t8qz to minikube
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "config"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "istio-galley-service-account-token-9pcmv"
  Warning  FailedMount            27s (x7 over 1m)  kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "certs" : secrets "istio.istio-galley-service-account" not found
```

after some time :-

```
 $ kubectl describe pod istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97

Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

so I wait for istio-sidecar-injector and istio-galley containers to get created. If I again run  **kubectl get pods -n istio-system** or any other **kubectl** commands gives **Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout** error.

Please help me with this issue.
ps: I'm running minikube on ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output for `kubectl describe pod istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97`

Comment: question updated please take a look.

Comment: Sorry: `kubectl -n istio-system describe pod istio-galley-6d74549bb9-mdc97`

Comment: updated the question please take a look.

Comment: @Mahendra Hegde, Does `minikube logs` command show any suspicious events?

Comment: thanks. Problem resolved. when I run minikube start --memory=4048. maybe it was a memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved. when I run `minikube start --memory=4048`. maybe it was a memory issue.

Comment: Almost certainly was; this is exactly how minikube behaves when it is short of either memory or CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running into [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7338) and [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7174) the secret `istio.istio-galley-service-account` is missing in your `istio-system` namespace. You can try the workaround as [described](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7174#issuecomment-429233168):

> Install as outlined in the docs: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/minimal-install/ the missing secret is created by the citadel pod which isn't running due to the --set security.enabled=false flag, setting that to true starts citadel and the secret is created.

Comment: sorry. that did not help. somehow gallery and ingress are running now. but  I'm facing the same problem with deployed applications.they are not initializing and after some time , I'm getting "Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout" error.

Answer (score 0):

When using either the `istio-demo.yaml` or `istio-demo-auth.yaml`, you'll find that a minimum of 4GB RAM is required to run Istio (particularly when you deploy its sample app, BookInfo, too). This is true whether your running MiniKube or Docker Desktop and is one of the gotchas that [Meshery](https://layer5.io/meshery) identifies and attempts to help those deploying Istio or other service meshes circumvent.